# Plane Wave in a Periodic Lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrons, crystals, plane-wave

From *Introduction to Superconductivity; Second Edition; A.C. Rose-Innes and E. H. Rhoderick; Page 3*

> Electrons have, of course, a wave-like nature, and an electron travelling through a metal can be represented by a plane wave progressing in the same direction. A metal has a crystalline structure with the atoms lying on a regular repetitive lattice, and it is a property of a plane wave that it can pass through a perfectly periodic structure without being scattered into other directions.

Can anyone demonstrate a proof?

Comment: Isn't this Bloch's theorem?